# Can multiple wordpress's feed off one database?

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, themes

I am a template designer and I want to create one wordpress with all generic posts, but I don't want to have to keep logging in and copy & pasteing the same wordpress posts everytime. Can I point multiple WP installs to one database? A harder way would be export a master db and importing it to each install. Before I go crazy and try to hack something together, does anyone have any advise?
-Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using this to showcase your various themes with example content, you're overcomplicating things. Use a theme switcher [like this one](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-switcher/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. They'd actually be various frontends to same backend.

Answer (score 0):

It should be doable in general, but the site's base URL and other configuration options are stored in the database, so it might not work entirely without problems.

If this is about fully functional blogs in production use, I would be very careful doing this. Better have a master database and copy the posts from there. If it's for demo purposes only, though, it should be fine.